# Extracting the domain extension of a URL stored in a string using scanf()

Tags: c, string

I am writing a code that takes a URL address as a string literal as input, then runs the domain extension of the URL through an array and returns the index if finds a match, `-1` if does not.

For example, an input would be `www.stackoverflow.com`, in this case, I'd need to extract only the `com` part. In case of `www.google.com.tr`, I'd need only `com` again, ignoring the `.tr` part.

I can think of basically writing a function that'll do that just fine but I'm wondering if it is possible to do it using `scanf()` itself?

Comment: That's not possible using `scanf`, it's not powerful enough. And it's going to be very hard using regular expressions as well. The problem is that sometime you want the last dot-separated part of the domain, and sometimes you want the second-to-last part. For example, if you have a domain like `foo.something.co.uk` what would the "domain extension" be? Or `www.bar.foo.info`?

Comment: I'm going to say no, due to URL's like `www.meta.stackoverflow.com`, or `https://stackoverflow.com`. `scanf` could do it if there were a fixed number of dots before the part you care about, but the number of dots is not fixed.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. So, I'll have to write a function. Just for sake of my curiosity, how'd I use `scanf` if I knew the amount of dots beforehand or if they were fixed?

Comment: `scanf("%*[^.].%[^./]", str)` will skip the first dot, and extract the string up to the next dot or slash.

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's really an overhead to use `scanf` here. But you can do this to realize something similar

```
char a[MAXLEN],b[MAXLEN],c[MAXLEN];
scanf("%[^.].%[^.].%[^. \n]",a,b,c);
printf("Desired part is = %s\n",c);
```

To be sure that formatting is correct you can check whether this `scanf` call is successful or not. For example:

```
if( 3 != scanf("%[^.].%[^.].%[^. \n]",a,b,c)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Format must be atleast sth.something.sth\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

What is the other way of achieving this same thing. Use `fgets` to read the whole line and then parse with `strtok` with delimiters `"."`. This way you will get parts of it. With `fgets` you can easily support different kind of rules. Instead of incorporating it in `scanf` (which will be a bit difficult in error case), you can use `fgets`,`strtok` to do the same.

With the solution provided above only the first three parts of the url is being considered. Rest are not parsed. But this is hardly the practical situation. Most the time we have to process the whole information, all the parts of the url (and we don't know how many parts can be there). Then you would be better using `fgets`/`strtok` as mentioned above.

Comment: The question actually originates from a Lab Guide that I'm solving only for practice but as far as I understand, the question actually wants me to extract the domain extension taking it for granted that the country extension will always be `.tr` but the number of dots not certain. That's why I can't use the `scanf()` function as I came to accept. In case which dots are also of fixed amount, your solution definitely works. I knew that too but I hoped there'd be more flexibility of `scanf()`. I'll take your suggestion into account and look into `fgets` and `strtok`! Thank you.

Comment: @SarpSTA.: Yep you are right, This solution with `scanf` takes every thing after second dot to the 3rd one and then put it in `c`. That's what it is. Good - that you would look `fgets`/`strtok`.